# How do I seal around a door to make the opening more sound-proof?

Tags: doors, sound-proofing

I live in an apartment condo.  The noise from the very loud neighbour comes through the door spaces. I wish to seal off all of her noise.  My walls are brick and are good. But the door going out to the common area has a varying gap around it.  At the top of the door, the gap is from 1/32" to 1/4" over a 32" length.  From the top of the door to the bottom of the door (not the floor), the gap is from 1/32" to 1/4 " over a 80" length.  The open space from the bottom of the door to the floor is from 3/4" to 1/2" extending 32" across the door.

As well, there is a wall air conditioner I'd like to seal.  I'm thinking about putting some acoustic caulking around the outside of the air conditioner (inside the house), but thought I'd mention that as well.  **My main concern is soundproofing the space around the door right now.**

I would like to sound proof these open areas effectively.  What can you suggest?   Obviously, I would like to witness the effectiveness of any materiel you suggest before purchasing it if possible.

Comment: To go from a gap of 1/32" to 1/4" over just 32" is a sign that the jamb is very crooked and the whole assembly needs to be rehung before you can really do anything.  Pending that, weather stripping would most likely take care of a lot of your problem.  However, as always with these types of questions, your options are severely limited if you're renting (apartment?).  Unless your landlord fixes that crooked jamb, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: The large gap under the door makes me wonder if the building requires air flow for the HVAC air return. If so, sealing that gap may make the apartment too hot or cold, or make the heat /AC work harder.

Comment: Remember that the door itself may not be a good sound barrier...

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into the sound seals used on STC rated doors. 
My apologies i forgot about  this so you can get some relief as follows.
You can purchase kits that consist of an automatic door sweep and perimeter seals.
example www.acousticalsolutions.com/door-seal-kits

Comment: this is maybe more of a comment than an answer. could you provide some additional information?

Comment: absolutely . I'll provide pictures monday

Comment: Link seems to be broken